# How to access arguments from a nested function passed in as a parameter

Tags: javascript, function

I am using a function as a parameter to build a reduce method. If the function that is passed in has no arguments, then I want to return 0.

```
_.reduce = function(arr, fun){
    if(fun[0] == undefined){
        return 0;
    }
.
.
```

The issue is that the if statement executes even if an argument is passed into fun. Am I trying to access the arguments incorrectly?

Comment: It may be helpful to provide an example of how you intend to use the `reduce` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to know how many arguments a function takes you should [check it's length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length).

```
_.reduce = function(arr, fun) {
  if (!fun || !fun.length) {
    return 0;
  }
  ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering your function "fun" is always defined, you can use the .length according to this link :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length

```
_.reduce = function(arr, fun){
if(fun.length == 0){
    return 0;
}
```